# PHP QR Code script - No GD2 Library

Tags: php

I have been googling with no luck.

I am searching for a php script to create and display QR Codes that doesn't require the GD2 Library.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Google Charts API: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/overview.html

Use an `img` element, with its `src` attribute in a particular format:

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=this%20is%20a%20demo" />
```

which produces:

[image]

The `chs` is the chart size, in this example 150px by 150px; the `cht` is the chart type, in this case `qr` and the `chl` is the chart's text to be encoded in url-encoded format.